# Javascript, get "this" from prototype function own field

Tags: javascript, prototype

Suppose I have following code:

```
var Model = function() {};
Model.prototype.a = function() {//do smth
Model.prototype.a.on = function() {//do smth

var m = new Model();
m.a();
m.a.on();
```

Now I need reference to specific object **m** from **m.a()** and **m.a.on()** calls.
When calling **m.a()**, i have **this** referring to **m**.

Is it possible to get reference to **m** from **m.a.on()** call somehow?

Comment: Why do you want to do that...

Comment: @ArunPJohny, namespacing, but it's a bad idea ayway :)

Comment: I have found convenient to use such constructions for object model library, because of auto completion IDE provides. So instead of writing obj.on("someString", callback), I can write obj.someString.on(callback), with extra-check from IDE on my field typing. It actually helps, as practice shows.

Comment: @Qwertiy Indeed it is, you should just use `.a_on(…)`

Comment: yes, that's solution I plan to apply, if .on is impossible )

Comment: @Vecnas, it is possible, but it shouldn't be implemented in that way :)

Comment: Why? I see your answer below, trying to realize what are bad cases.

Comment: Thank you all, I'll investigate question referred as original, hope find bad cases there )

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very bad idea to do so, as it leads to very strange behaviour in some cases, but it's possible:

```js
var Model = function(x) { this.x = x };

Object.defineProperty(Model.prototype, 'a', (function() {
  var lastSelf;
  function get() { return lastSelf.x }
  get.on = function () { return lastSelf.x * 2 };
  return { get() { lastSelf=this; return get } };
})());

var m = new Model(17);
console.log(m.a(), m.a.on());
```

> Why? I see your answer below, trying to realize what are bad cases.

You can't pass `a` through the variable.
You must grant access to `on` immediately after getting property `a` of the same object:

```js
var Model = function(x) { this.x = x };

Object.defineProperty(Model.prototype, 'a', (function() {
  var lastSelf;
  function get() { return lastSelf.x }
  get.on = function () { return lastSelf.x * 2 };
  return { get() { lastSelf=this; return get } };
})());

var m1 = new Model(1), m2 = new Model(3);
console.log(m1.a(), m2.a(), m1.a.on(), m2.a.on()); // 1 3 2 6 - ok
var a1 = m1.a, a2 = m2.a;
console.log(m1.a(), m2.a(), a1.on(), a2.on()); // 1 3 6 6 - ooops!
console.log(m1.a(), m2.a(), m1.a(), a1.on(), a2.on()); // 1 3 1 2 2 - ooops!
```

---

And the other solution, but with using `__proto__`. According to ES6 this solution is valid for browser enviroments and for server enviroments `__proto__` have to be replaced by `Object.setPrototypeOf`. Be sure to check [browser support](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) and other warnings.

This solution adds 1 function and 1 object per each instance.

```js
function Model(x) { 
  this.x = x;

  this.a = function () { return Model.prototype.a.call(this, arguments) };
  this.a.__proto__ = Object.create(Model.prototype.a);
  this.a.this = this;
}

Model.prototype.a = function () { return this.x };
Model.prototype.a.on = function () { return this.this.x * 2 };

var m1 = new Model(1), m2 = new Model(3);
console.log([m1.a(), m2.a(), m1.a.on(), m2.a.on()] == "1,3,2,6");
var a1 = m1.a, a2 = m2.a;
console.log([m1.a(), m2.a(), a1.on(), a2.on()] == "1,3,2,6");
console.log([m1.a(), m2.a(), m1.a(), a1.on(), a2.on()] == "1,3,1,2,6");
```

Comment: I suppose any prototype based function has listed drawbacks. We can't bind it to specific object, because of prototype nature, and owning object lost when passing function as callback or variable.

Comment: @Vecnas, maybe it's possible via ES6 `Proxy` - have to think about that.

Comment: @Vecnas, updated the answer.

Comment: interesting, i'll try this

Answer (score 1):

You can rebind the 'grandchild' methods manually in the constructor:

```
bindAll = function(self, obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
        if(typeof obj[k] === 'function')
            obj[k] = obj[k].bind(self);
    });
}

var Model = function() {
    bindAll(this, this.a);
    this.x = 123;
};

Model.prototype.a = function() {}
Model.prototype.a.on = function() {
    console.log(this.x);
}

var m = new Model();
m.a();
m.a.on();
```

A more memory-savvy way is to use an explicit pointer to the root class and consistently use `this.root` instead of just `this` in methods:

```
var Model = function(x) {
    this.x = x;
    this.model = this;
    this.a = Object.create(this.a);
    this.a.model = this;
};

Model.prototype.a = function() {
    console.log(this.model.x);
}
Model.prototype.a.on = function() {
    console.log(this.model.x);
};

var m1 = new Model(11), m2 = new Model(22);
m1.a.on();
m2.a.on();
m1.a.on();
```

Comment: What if I create about 10,000 objects? Initially I didn't use prototypes, re-written to improve performance for such cases.

Comment: I'll check this,looks simple )

Comment: If you create 10,000 objects, this code will create 10,000 x number_of_methods closures ;( If you're not happy with the default `this` you have to store your `this` somewhere.

Comment: @Vecnas: added a more efficient solution.

Comment: thank you, i'll check it and report )

Comment: Your second solution is wrong. Just create 2 objects.

Comment: @Qwertiy: not sure what you mean by this. Care to elaborate?

Comment: yes, second is wrong, it refers to same object, just checked it, behaves like static variable

Comment: Initially I think it's impossible to keep tracking of this, because .a defined via prototype, so it looks like static

Comment: `var Model = function(x) {
    this.x = x;
    this.model = this.a.model = this;
};

Model.prototype.a = function() {
    console.log(this.model.x);
};

Model.prototype.a.on = function() {
    console.log(this.model.x);
};

var m1 = new Model(1), m2 = new Model(2);
m1.a(), m1.a.on(), m2.a(), m2.a.on();` The result is `1 2 2 2` when `1 1 2 2` is expected.

Comment: @Vecnas, yes it's so.

Comment: @Qwertiy: I see now, thanks, fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately we loosing all prototype gain due to creation of .a separately for every object. That's what I trying to get rid of (

Comment: @Vecnas, no, we don't. Or I don't undestand what you are talking about. There is no deep cloning, just a new object.

Comment: @Vecnas: yes, but the cloned objects will be rather tiny as they contain only `proto` and `model`. I think it's a reasonable price.

Comment: I did simple test, creating 10k objects with 2 functions, one variant - functions were added per object, second - set via prototypes. Very different performance. I'll check performance of proposed solution too, not sure about results

Comment: @Vecnas: actually, the 2nd version still doesn't work if you want `a` to be a function (`m1.a()` won't work). ;(

Comment: Just put you object into function's `__proto__`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: I tried, but couldn't find a solution without wrapping `a` in a closure. Care to share your approach?

Comment: Updated my answer. It was a bit more compicated than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access directly the parent object from a.on. You have to define some property (e.g. parent) linked to main object before calling a.on:

```
var Model = function() {};
Model.prototype.a = function() {//do smth
  console.log(this.i);
}
Model.prototype.a.on = function() {//do smth
  console.log(this.parent.i);
}

var m = new Model();
m.i = 11;
m.a();
m.a.parent = m
m.a.on();
```

Comment: Assigning parent manually every time you need to call the method is a very bad solution. By the way you can use `call` instead: `m.a.on.call(m)`.